# How to rewrite a specific URL to 404 but allow access to that same URL by another rewritten URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a specific file (lets call this file the `file-handler`) on my server which should handle all requests to files with a specific extension. The `file-handler` itself should however not directly be accessible.

What I tried:

- Place the `file-handler` in a password protected directory. Unfortunately any URL rewritten to that specific directory causes the browser (hence the server) to ask for the password, so this method doesn't work.
- Rewrite direct access to the `file-handler` to the default 404 page, Unfortunately any URL rewritten to the `file-handler` causes mod_rewrite to serve the 404 page.

*Source for second attempt:*

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule dontallowdirectaccess\.xxx$ - [R=404,L]

#Only serve existing files to the file-handler
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.ext$ dontallowdirectaccess.xxx [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first 404 enforcing rule use `THE_REQUEST` variable. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from the browser and **it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules** unlike `REQUEST_URI` variable.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /dontallowdirectaccess\.xxx[?\s/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

#Only serve existing files to the file-handler
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule \.ext$ dontallowdirectaccess.xxx [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working, although I removed the [?\s/] part. It doesn't work however when I replace the [?\s/] part with the end-of-string flag ($), it just serves me the page, why is that?

Comment: Because `$` means end of input whereas example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1` so it doesn't end with URI itself.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that their is actually another way to do this which doesn't require you to parse the `{THE_REQUEST}` variable.

```
#Only serve existing files to the file-handler (directories not included)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (^.+\.ext$) dontallowdirectaccess.xxx?file=$1 [QSA,L]

#If ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS is empty than someone must be trying to access the file directly.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule dontallowdirectaccess\.xxx$ - [R=404,L]
```